# how to allow only one specific class to create other class instances

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture, c++17

`MyDataConatiner` is kind of facade to `MyData`.

I Dont want to allow other classes to create `Mydata` .
it has  some logic of  lazy instantiation that I want to keep in `MyDataConatiner` .

thought about something like private ctor with friend class , but I am not sure.

or is it something with  one of factory design patterns

Comment: Make `MyData` constructor (or, equivalently, destructor) private, and make `MyDataConatiner` a friend. Then `MyDataConatiner` would indeed act as a factory for `MyData` instances.

Comment: Put your MyData definition in cpp (together with implementation of MyDataConatiner - so only it will see MyData class)
When creating MyData - return its public interface IMyData which does not expose any possibility to create the implementation of the interface.
So anyone who want to get instance of class implementing interface will have to go through Factory class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to make `MyDataContainer` a friend of `MyData` as shown below:

```
class MyData 
{
  //befriend MyDataContainer so that MyDataContainer can create object of type MyData
  friend class MyDataContainer;
  
  //private converting ctor that can be used by MyDataContainer but not normal users
  MyData(int)
  {
      
  }
};
class MyDataContainer
{
    public: 
        //add method(s) for creating MyData object 
        
    //other code here   
};
```